# How can I tell which radio button is selected with node.js

Tags: node.js, forms, post, express, body-parser

I have a form with two radio button and I'm using posting the request and using the body parser npm package to see the values of the form inputs, I have two radio buttons on the form like this:

```html
    <p>
      <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="test1" />
      <label for="test1">Teacher</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="test2" />
      <label for="test2">TA</label>
    </p>
```

The only problem is when I console.log req.body the only info on the radio buttons I get is:

```js
{ group1: 'on' }
```

It doesn't tell me which radio button was clicked and I change one of the names to group2 it allows the user to click both radio buttons, so how can I determine which radio button was clicked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should give the radio-buttons a attribute of value. Like:

```
<input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="test1" value="test1"/>
```

It should make the object from body-parser read {group1:"test1"}

Comment: I dont understand this answer... the value of for example three radios might be different and when i res.body.id_name them, they each give me a value regardless of whether they were toggled or not

Comment: Of course the value might be different, that's exactly the point of the question @ingrid I needed to know which one was clicked which would have a different value from the other two

Answer (score 2):

On the client side you would use $('#id').prop( "checked" ), on the server side you would use req.body.name_of_input